# binding a ref does not work in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

When I v-bind a element-ref with `:ref="testThis"` it stops working it seems. Compare [this version](https://codesandbox.io/s/9437494r5w) which works:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <q-btn round big color='red' @click="IconClick">
        YES
        </q-btn>
        <div>
            <input
                ref="file0"
                multiple
                type="file"
                accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.bmp,.JPG"
                @change="testMe"
                style='opacity:0'
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { QBtn } from 'quasar-framework'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
    components: {           
         QBtn
    },
    data () {
    return {
      file10: 'file0'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    IconClick () {
      this.$refs['file0'].click()
    },
        testMe () {
            console.log('continue other stuff')
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

With [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqyll10z9z) which DOES NOT work:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <q-btn round big color='red' @click="IconClick">
        YES
        </q-btn>
        <div>
            <input
                :ref="testThis"
                multiple
                type="file"
                accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.bmp,.JPG"
                @change="testMe"
                style='opacity:0'
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { QBtn } from 'quasar-framework'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
    components: {           
         QBtn
    },
    data () {
    return {
      file10: 'file0'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    IconClick () {
      this.$refs['file0'].click()
    },
        testThis () {
            return 'file0'
        },
        testMe () {
            console.log('continue other stuff')
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

The first one works. The second one throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at VueComponent.IconClick
```

As I would like to vary the ref based on a list-index (not shown here, but it explains my requirement to have a binded ref) I need the binding. Why is it not working/ throwing the error?

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you expect?

Comment: @dvnguyen Edited my question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I see. You changed the `ref` to `testThis` and since `testThis` is a method which returns `file0`, you expect the `ref` would be assigned to `file0`? I'm afraid that couldn't work, since `:ref` only accepts strings as my understanding.

Comment: @dvnguyen Uh.., but I am handing it a string?

Comment: You're handing it the string "testThis", right? So the ref at this point would be "testThis". to make IconClick work, you need to change the ref name to "testThis": `this.$refs['testThis'].click()`

Comment: Not really. When using binding the 'testThis' turns into a reference to the method, which return a string.

Comment: I would think a `computed` or `data` item would make more sense than a method as a binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vue docs I [find](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) that a ref is non-reactive: "$refs is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding."

I think that matches my case.

My actual problem 'how to reference an item of a v-for list' is NOT easily solved not using a binded ref as vue puts all similar item-refs in an array, BUT [it loses (v-for index) order](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952).

I have another rather elaborate single file component which works fine using this piece of code:

```
 :ref="'file' + parentIndex.toString()"
```

in an input element. The only difference from my question example is that `parentIndex` is a component property.

All in all it currently is kind of confusing as from [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3842) it looks like binding ref was allowed in earlier vue version.

EDIT:
Triggering the method with `testThis()` [does work](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz10k1qpvy).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a method, you will need to use the invocation parentheses in the binding to let Vue know you want it to bind the result of the call and not the function itself.

```
             :ref="testThis()"
```

I think the snippet below works as you expect it to. I use a `computed` rather than a method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      file10: 'file0'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    testThis() {
      return 'file0';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    IconClick() {
      this.$refs['file0'].click()
    },
    testMe() {
      console.log('continue other stuff')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <q-btn round big color='red' @click="IconClick">
    YES
  </q-btn>
  <div>
    <input :ref="testThis" multiple type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.bmp,.JPG" @change="testMe" style='opacity:0'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A computed does not take an argument so I can not hand it the v-for index value. A watch might work, but seems a bit overdoing it.

Comment: In your example, you aren't passing anything to the method; you aren't even invoking it. A watch would not be suitable for a `v-for` index value. Just invoke the function and it should work.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. You're right, and I had adjusted it in my answer above using a method as that works fine as well as shown in fiddle. However when I use the v-for index as an argument and concatenate it as part of the ref and then reference it, it recognizes the ref, but still keeps giving error when using .click() on it somehow. I hacked this problem by adding an `:id=vforIndex` to the element. The index is returned in the input-event as `event.target.id` and when I use that in combination with the ref I can find the element and .click() somehow works then. Hope it makes a bit of sense!

Comment: Genious! That solved my problem. That little bit of `()` did the trick. How to pass an element to if so that I can save it?